# Wrapper-Classes for Unit-Tests

Tags: java, junit, mockito, wrapper, sap-commerce-cloud

I am in the position to write some Unit-Tests and with that Refactoring. We are using Hybris. What you can see very often are Trainwrecks. For example: `cmsSiteService.getCurrentSite().getSlaveSalesOrganization()` and so on.

Now writing Unit-Tests and mocking the responses, I would in this case first mock a CurrentSite and declare `doReturn(currentSite).when(cmsSiteService.getCurrentSite)` and then `doReturn(slaveSalesOrganization).when(currentSite).getSlaveSalesOrganization()`.

This Example is rather short, but with the cmsSiteService it happens all over the project. Since the cmsSiteService is a third-party Hybris class, I thought it would be good to write a wrapper-class which inherits everything from the CMSSiteService-Class. There I could write a method getSlaveSalesOrganizationFromCurrentSite(CMSSiteService cmsSiteService) where I would call everything above.

Is this recommended or is there a better solution designwise?

Comment: I think your question might be clearer with some actual examples.

Comment: What you *may* be looking for is [RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS), I guess?

Comment: I faced same pattern in code and decided to write one test class that mocks away all the common patterns and gives protected access to the mocks. The actual unit tests then all inherited from that "super-test" and could choose to add mocked meaning to the individual items.

Comment: The thing is, it's not only about making Unit-Tests easier, but also to substitute the normal CMSSiteService-class with my wrapper, all over my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're on the right track. What you're doing is refactoring your code to better adhere to the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), also known as the "principle of least knowledge". Digging through object chains like you say is an anti-pattern for exactly the reason you've encountered: when objects are tightly coupled, they are hard to modify and test.

Ideally, you would add a `getSlaveSalesOrganizationFromCurrentSite` method to your `CMSSiteService` class, if you're allowed to modify that code. I think creating a wrapper to simplify an ugly interface is a great second option. That would be an implementation of the [Adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). It's a great way to prevent your own code from tightly coupling to (someone else's) crappy code.